Prior to C# 11, every field in a struct had to be explicitly assigned? Cannot reproduce
According to the book C#12 in a Nutshell:

Prior to C# 11, every field in a struct had to be explicitly assigned
in the constructor (or field initializer). This restriction has now
been relaxed.

However this:
using System;

Point point = new Point();
Console.WriteLine(point.X);

struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

compiles and runs (returns 0) when compiled with .NET 5 (which is C#9 if I understand correctly? source: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0).
MRE: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K6cu5z.

.NET version is somewhat independent of the C# version. Visual Studio determines what C# version you have, and uses a process called lowering to compile to IL. Newer C# features often lower to still work on older .NET.

I'm using Rider not Visual Studio, I don't know if this applies?

The code you've written has always been fine - you're calling the parameterless constructor, which assigns all fields to their default values.
If you change your code to:
Point point;
Console.WriteLine(point.X); // Error

... then you'll see the error.
Note that if you fully initialize it - without ever calling new - it's fine:
Point point;
point.X = 10;
point.Y = 20;
Console.WriteLine(point.X); // Fine

But in terms of the book's text, if it says: "every field had to be explicitly assigned in the constructor (or field initializer)" then that doesn't say anything about your code, because you don't declare any constructors.
Here's an example which actually demonstrates that rule:
struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Point(int x)
    {
        X = x;
        // Error before C# 11: Y isn't assigned
    }
}

If you build this with <LangVersion>10</LangVersion> you'll get an error; use <LangVersion>11</LangVersion> and it builds.

I see. Does that mean that the parameterless constructor assigns every field to their default value?

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows: Yes, it does, and always has. I've edited my answer quite a bit though, to give an example of what the text is actually talking about.
